# Amazon S3 secret key page moving

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, secret-key

I have recently logged into my amazon s3 account to get my secret key for setup and i am greeted with the following alert.

> Note: Please use the new page named Your Security Credentials in the
>   AWS Management Console to manage security credentials. AWS will
>   support the current page for a limited time to help during your
>   transition.

What does this mean i need to do with my php sdk setup when this page goes because i access amazon s3 with the following within my code.

```
/**
     * Create a list of credential sets that can be used with the SDK.
     */
    CFCredentials::set(array(

        // Credentials for the development environment.
        'development' => array(

            'key' => $as3key,
            'secret' => $assecretkey,
            'default_cache_config' => '',
            'certificate_authority' => false
        ),

        '@default' => 'development'
    ));  

    $s3 = new AmazonS3();
```

I was wondering if someone could update me on how the php sdk will deal with this when the security secret key goes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change your code, the SDK is still the same. It's just for the AWS administration dashboard that they made a separate section just for credentials.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you should always be using the key/secret for an IAM sub-account with properly-scoped permissions. You should not be using your root credentials for anything. That is considered a *Bad Practice™*.

Secondly, AWS SDK for PHP 1.6.x hasn't been updated in quite a while, and users are strongly encouraged to migrate to SDK 2.x sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS access key id and AWS secret access key are not changing.  How you use these credentials is not changing.  Your PHP code does not need to change.

The only thing that is changing is where you go on the AWS web site to find out what your AWS credentials are, and you presumably already know what they are.